# Multidimensional Arrays vs. Array of Arrays in Response DTO

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, servicestack, dto

I have a DTO that I'm using with the ServiceStack 'JsonServiceClient', and it appears a multidimensional array arrives as 'null' on my client side, while an array of arrays is tramsitted to the client without issues.

My DTO's Fields :

```
public int totalCount { get; set; }
public myTypes.Util.ColumnHeader[] columnHeaders { get; set; }
public string[,] dataRows { get; set; }
public string[][] dataArray { get; set; }
```

I'd prefer to use the `[,]` syntax (second dimension of the array cant be variable with `[,]`), so I was wondering if this is a known issue or if I'm just making a mistake somewhere.

On the server, during debug, I can see the same data in the `string[,]` and again in the `string[][]`, but on the client side, only `string[][]` is populated with data, what is going on?

Comment: Does the JSON serializer support multidimensional arrays?

Comment: @odyss-jii it's the ServiceStack JSON Serializer, I suppose you've just summed up my question into a single line.